# How to send an image to third party when the content type is multipart/form-data ? How to add two parameters while sending a request?

Tags: cpq

I have to send an images to third party system and content type provided is multipart/formdata and I have to add two parameters in it. and then want to send the request. How to send 2 parameters in it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have two parameters then it supposed to be separated by a boundary parameter.
Syntax for adding 2 parametrs in a request : Sometimes unique boundary creates a problem, so I generate it dynamically in salesforce.

```
    integer randomNumber = Math.round(math.random()*999999999);
    String boundary = '__boundary__123'+String.valueOf(randomNumber);
    String footer = '\n--'+boundary+'--';
    String header = '--'+boundary+'\n';
    header += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="media"; 
    filename="'+file_name+'"';
    header += '\n--'+boundary +'\n';
```